# Как решить проблему MemoryError при считывании больших Excel файлов?

Tags: python, парсер, pandas, excel, dataframe

При считывании методом `read_excel()` появляется ошибка:

> MemoryError: unable to allocate 32.1 mib for an array with shape (10081, 834) and data type object

Работаю с очень большими файлами Excel формата. Есть несколько листов, в каждом по 8к строк и около 1к столбцов. Нужно все конвертировать в один CSV файл. Изначально планировал считывать каждый лист в отдельный DataFrame, а после - соединить их все в один и записать его в CSV файл, но столкнулся с ошибкой выше.

Comment: Проверьте сколько памяти потребляет программа. Вероятно, всю доступную.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**NOTE:** судя по тому, что вы хотите писасть несколько листов Excel файла **в единственный CSV файл**, в решении я буду исходить из того, что во всех листах совпадают имена столбцов.

Пример функции, которая читает по кускам (размер куска управляется параметром `chunksize`) все листы Excel файла и сохраняет результат в CSV файл:

```python
import pandas as pd

def excel_to_csv(excel_fn, csv_fn, chunksize=1000, **to_csv_kw):    
    ef = pd.ExcelFile(excel_fn)
    cols = ef.parse(nrows=10).columns
    # write to CSV column names ONLY (we do it once!)
    pd.DataFrame([], columns=cols).to_csv(csv_fn, index=False, **to_csv_kw)
    for sheet in ef.sheet_names:
        rows_read = 0
        while True:
            df = ef.parse(
                    sheet_name=sheet,
                    skiprows=1+rows_read,
                    nrows=chunksize,
                    header=None,
                    names=cols)
            df.to_csv(csv_fn, index=False, header=None,
                      mode="a", **to_csv_kw)
            rows_read += len(df)
            if len(df) < chunksize:
                break
```

Примеры вызова:

```
excel_to_csv(r"c:\download\file.xlsx", r"c:\temp\out.csv", chunksize=2000, sep=";")
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема может быть связана с движком, который использует [read_excel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html), по умолчанию это [xlrd](https://github.com/python-excel/xlrd), но даже у них на гитхабе в первой же строчке написано, что стоит использовать [openpyxl](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/). Так что попробуйте другой engine.

Более того, вам совершенно не нужен pandas, если необходимо  просто сконвертировать xlsx в csv. Достаточно использовать openpyxl https://stackoverflow.com/a/10803229/9569886