# Как по частям считать большой документ Excel с несколькими листами?

Tags: python, pandas, excel, dataframe

Допустим, у меня есть один большой документ Excel, который  состоит из нескольких листов (сколько строк и столбцов в каждом точно не известно).

Можно ли организовать какой-либо цикл для парсинга всех листов, при этом каждый лист считывать по частям (допустим по 1000 строк) в DataFrame?

Answer (score 2):

В [вашем предыдущем вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1172436/211923)  вы сказали, что получаете `MemoryError` при попытке прочитать все данные из одного листа Excel файла. Соответственно если попытаться прочитать все данные в Pandas.DataFrame, который целиком хранится в памяти, вы получите ту же ошибку - `MemoryError`.

В качестве решения можно воспользоваться Dask.DataFrame, который позволяет работать с фреймами, которые не умещаются в памяти:

```
# (c) zorze https://stackoverflow.com/a/53445829/5741205
import dask
import dask.dataframe as dd
from dask.delayed import delayed

parts = dask.delayed(pd.read_excel)(excel_file, sheet_name=0, usecols = [1, 2, 7])
df = dd.from_delayed(parts)

print(df.head())
```

PS стоит упомянуть, что это не дается "бесплатно", операции с Dask.DataFrame занимают гораздо больше времени по сравнению с Pandas.DataFrame

Comment: Спасибо)
но я не пытаюсь все считать в DataFrame. Идея в том, чтобы считывать по частям один лист, заносить его в csv файл, потом считывать другую часть и тоже заносить. По сути у меня нет одного DataFrame и ошибки с памятью быть не должно. Проблема в том, как реализовать считывание по частям

Comment: @ego_xxx, у меня «дежа вю»? ;) Именно это я и показал в моем ответе на ваш предыдущий вопрос